# Play multiple audio files in Discord py with FFmpegPCMAudio

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

Im attempting to make a discord piano bot. Below i have the commands to play two notes, a and b respectively. This code works, but it is unable to overlap the audio files, or cancel playing an audio file when another command is run. I get the error: "discord.errors.ClientException: Already playing audio." which seems obvious, but I thought it may be useful for context.

```
@commands.command()
    async def a(self, ctx):
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("A3.mp3")
        ctx.voice_client.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def b(self, ctx):
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("B3.mp3")
        ctx.voice_client.play(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you any specific suggestions on discord.py but I can give you a pointer on what needs to be done as I've done something similar in a completely different context in the past (waaay before the age of internet streaming).

First, the problem has nothing to do with FFmpeg and has everything to do with how discord.py handles audio playback. The bottom line is that your error indicates that each `voice_client.play()` call basically occupies the audio stream, preventing you to do anything else with the stream until it's done playing what it was instructed to play.

What you need is an audio mixer device, which can combine multiple audio signals before it pushes out the mix to the audio stream as well as the audio device to accept a stream from the mixer so the playback is seamless.

You can poke around the discord.py to see if either of these functionalities are available. The stream audio input must be supported by the library, but you can implement your own software mixer around the streaming mechanism.

Another possibility is MIDI. If there is a support for MIDI, it may give you much finer control but steeper learning curve.